# Can I host a dynamic Flask application on GitHub pages?

Tags: flask, github-pages

I have a web app made with Flask and I want to host it on GitHub pages. However, GitHub pages can't run Python apps, and I can't use something like Frozen-Flask because my app is dynamic.

Comment: hmm i believe they can only host static content, perhaps try a [hosted service](https://aws.amazon.com/free/compute/lightsail/)

Comment: No, but you can run Flask on [Glitch](https://glitch.com/~flask-office-starter) for free